# Convert tabs to spaces in Adobe Flash IDE when writing Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tabs, flash-cs6, spaces

I'm writing Actionscript in the Adobe Flash CS6 IDE. The code is becoming hard to read because the IDE is using hard tabs. These hard tabs are mixed with other co-workers soft tabs, causing [inconsistent indentation](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/13/never-use-hard-tabs/). I'm seeing poor indentation like this:

```
    if (this.logo.visible) {
    rightSideButtons.push( this.logo );
    rightSideButtonSeparators.push( this.chrome.separatorLogo );
    }
```

How do I configure the IDE to only use soft tabs comprised of 4 spaces? That setting conforms to our company's coding standard.

The settings don't show a way to convert tabs to spaces. They only show a configuration for tab size:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The code editor in Flash is awful, you should use [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org/) instead.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't a novel idea to you, but have you considered using another code IDE? The Flash Pro code editing is widely regarded as pretty bare bones. You could try FlashDevelop (Windows) or FDT (OSX) for free, both are much better than the Flash Pro code editor and support spaces for indentation.

Comment: I have considered other IDE's. Ususally, if it's a third party IDE, then it doesn't do a good job of autocompleting the first party SDK... Just tried installing FlashDevelop. Got an error saying I need to downgrade my Java runtime to 32-bit. What??? This tool is not professional...

Comment: FlashDevelop has always worked really well for me. For pro tools I would recommend Adobe Flash Builder or IntelliJ IDEA. There's actually a free version of IntelliJ IDEA but I believe it doesn't include AS3/Flex support.

Comment: I use Flash IDE since its CS3 version and I never encounter such problem, and currently I use its CS 5.5 and CS 6 versions and It's working well.

Comment: @akmozo Maybe you don't have co-workers that use other text editors that have the common 4 space soft tab setting.

Comment: @Pwner In that case, you can use the "Auto format" button which will, as its name indicate, format automatically the code according to settings that you have already chosen.

Comment: @akmozo Autoformatting would make my editor look good, but may cause trouble in my co-worker's editor. The autoformat in the Flash IDE would turn everything into hard tabs. You can read many articles about why hard tabs can screw you over, including [this article](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/13/never-use-hard-tabs/).

Comment: Flash can take one app and publish to both IOS and Android and it's not professional because of the tab in the code editor?  Your co-worker needs to change his editor to work with Adobe's.

Comment: @Pwner, if you are looking for performance, refactoring, organization and lots of reasons, you should try FDT, I'm using since the first version and have nothing to complain.